# Quick method to combine (x,y) pixel value of multiple images?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, image, performance, numpy

I have 10 1944 x 2546 binary images stored in a nparray `images`.
I would like to read the pixel value of each pixel on the 10 images and combine them into a string of 0s and 1s (such as '1001101100') and store them into a 2D array `output`. So far I am using a nested `for` loop, which is very slow. Therefore, I wonder if there is any smarter approach to achieve the same result. My current code is as follow:

```
output = [()]
for y in range(0,image_height):
    for x in range(0,image_width):
        code_string = ''
        for n in range(0,len(images)-2):
            code_string = code_string + str(images[n][y,x]/255)
        output.append(code_string)
```

Comment: That's an odd thing to do! Do you care to say what you plan to do with the strings afterwards? Have you maybe considered storing them as bits within an integer for each location? Then you could operate on them with logical ANDs, ORs, XORs.

Comment: I am decoding a series of gray code structured light pattern (ultimately for 3D scene reconstruction) and therefore I need to obtain a string like '1001101100' for each pixel. This information will help to provide spatial correspondence between 2 cameras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
# create 0, 255 arrays
imgs = [255 * np.random.randint(0, 2, (1944,2546)) for i in range(10)]

# binarize them, convert to int32, stack them along the last axis,
# add the offset of character '0' and view-cast to unicode
binstr = (np.r_[('2,3,0', *map(np.int32, map(np.bool8, imgs)))] + ord('0')).view('U10').squeeze()
binstr
# array([['0010110011', '0101011101', '0001000000', ..., '1011101100',
#         '1110011110', '0011110111'],
#        ['1101110100', '0000001000', '0000100101', ..., '0000110100',
#         '1000010011', '0001101011'],
#        ['0100011100', '0111101001', '0001011001', ..., '1111011111',
#         '0110100000', '0001111000'],
#        ...,
#        ['0100000110', '1000000000', '0000001011', ..., '1001110001',
#         '1001010000', '0010010111'],
#        ['0011100010', '0110010101', '0011111000', ..., '1011100101',
#         '1011001111', '1100011011'],
#        ['0011111101', '0000001101', '1110011011', ..., '1011110100',
#         '0001010010', '0001010010']], dtype='<U10')
```

Conversion takes half a second on my laptop.

Comment: Thank you! This code can achieve the result at high speed. One addition question is that, instead of getting something like '0011111101', i get 'įį0į000000'. Any idea on why would I get a symbol instead of 1?

Comment: @yukchingleung I suspect it is because your input is not `0`s and `1`s, but `0`s and `255`s. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @yukchingleung Done. Pls have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You might get a small speedup by not creating and appending to a string iteratively, but only once after gathering the bits across the images:

```
    code_string = []
    for n in range(0,len(images)-2):
        code_string.append(images[n][y,x]/255)
    output.append(''.join(code_string))
```

The probably better way would be to load the images into numpy-arrays and slice&dice them correctly - my numpyfu is not good enough for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the slowest part is calling 10 x 1944 x 2546 append command.

You can reshape that images to shape (1944x2546, 10) table, and if you want to have list, use X.tolist() command at the end.

```
images_bool = images < 256
output = images_bool.transpose((1,2,0)).reshape((1944*2546,10)).tolist()
```

Why the conversion to the strings?